# How to access a Map using playframework template system (groovy)

Tags: groovy, playframework

I've been using the--quite excellent--playframework and have had trouble finding documentation/examples on how to access a Map data structure from a view, using play's template engine.

To be even more specific, I wish to access the Map as I iterate over a List of objects, e.g.,

```
#{list items:itemList, as:'item'}
 // access the map value using the ${item?.id} as the key
#{/list}
```

Thank's for looking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you do in the Controller:

```
render(map, itemList); //map is a Map
```

This **should** work:

```
#{list items:itemList, as:'item'}
 // access the map value using the ${item?.id} as the key
 ${map.get(item.?id)}
#{/list}
```

Answer (score 21):

This is a **generic solution** to iterate on *Map* in using Play! Framework:

in the controller :

```
render(map);
```

in the template:

```
#{list items:map.keySet(), as:'key'}
   ${map.get(key)}
#{/list}
```

The fact that you want to rely on a side *List* to iterate on your *Map* suggest me that you are searching a predictible way for your iteration process.

In that case, just remember that iteration will be unpredictable if you don't use an ordered/sorted *Map* implementation.

- **HashMap** gives you an **unsorted**, **unordered** *Map*

  **LinkedHashMap** maintains **insertion order**

  **TreeMap** is the only JDK implementation of a **sorted** *Map*. By default it allows you to iterate following the **natural order** of the elements. You can also specify a custom sort order and implements the **[Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)** interface. This will lead you to override the *compareTo()* method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about the play framework, but this would work in a GSP

```
#{list items:itemList, as:'item'}
 ${map[item?.id]}
#{/list}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing things like that on a map:

```
*{ Map<User, Integer> shareHolders = ... }*
#{list shareHolders.sort{it.value}.collect {k,v -> k}.reverse(), as:'holder'}
    <tr>
        <td>${holder.name}</td>
        <td>${shareHolders[holder]}</td>
    </tr>
#{/list}
```