# how to render Map<String, String> to template and use there

Tags: java, dictionary, playframework-2.0

i am trying to render a key,value Map to a template and then show there in this way:

```
@(twittsIfollow: Map[String, String])
 .....
 @if(twittsIfollow != null) {
  @for((key, value) <- twittsIfollow) {
    @key
    @value
   } 
 }
```

it says, it is wrong. is there a scala tag for Map keys values?

here is my method:

```
public static Map<String, String> alltwitts(List<Long> otherIDs) {
    Map<String, String> results=new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (Long id: otherIDs) {
        Query selected_twitt = JPA.em().createQuery("select u.twitt from Twitt u where " + " u.whose = ?").setParameter(1, id);
        String twOwner = User.getOneUser(id);
        String twitt  = (String) selected_twitt.getSingleResult();
        results.put(twOwner, twitt);
    }

    return results;
}
```

then i render to template in this place:

```
Map<String, String> twittsIfollow = Twitt.alltwitts(IDusersIamFollowing);
return ok(microblog.render(twittsIfollow));
```

now it is saying: `[NonUniqueResultException: result returns more than one elements]`

thanks

Comment: Does this helps?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750210/how-to-access-a-map-using-playframework-template-system-groovy

Comment: no because this is not scala template engine, i am using playframework2.0 which uses scala template engine..

Comment: Sorry, I'm not proficient with playframework but remembered seing that post sometime ago and thought it might help. Good luck.

Comment: no problem, thanks for attempt to help. man! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply

```
@for((key, value) <- twittsIfollow) {
  @key
  @value
}
```

BTW, if you are using Scala, `twittsIfollow` should never be null. Prefer using `Option`.

Comment: i put this ``if else`` is it a good protection against ``null``

Comment: ``@if(twittsIfollow != null) {...``

Comment: i am getting this error: 

``[NonUniqueResultException: result returns more than one elements]``

Answer (score 3):

how i solved:

```
    public static Map<String, List<String>> alltwitts(List<Long> otherIDs) { 
    Map<String, List<String>> results=new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    for (Long id: otherIDs) {                       
        Query selected_twitt = JPA.em().createQuery("select twitt from Twitt where " + " whose = ? order by id").setParameter(1, id);
        String twOwner = User.getOneUser(id);
        List<String> twitt  = selected_twitt.getResultList();
        results.put(twOwner, twitt);

    }
    System.out.println(results);
    return results;
}
```

then in my Application:

```
Map<String, List<String>> twittsIfollow = Twitt.alltwitts(IDusersIamFollowing);
return ok(microblog.render(twittsIfollow));
```

then in my template:

```
@(twittsIfollow: Map[String, List[String]])
```

and

```
@if(twittsIfollow != null) {
  @for((key, value) <- twittsIfollow) {
  @for(innervalue <- value){
            Username: @key
            Twitt: @innervalue
        } 
      } 
 }
```

just for those who are dumb like me :D and looking for solution like this..

thanks for help,guys..

Answer (score 1):

@doniyor, I'm surpriesed as I showed you the way in [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11273097/1066240) not so long ago.

By the way I think it will be better to build, pass and iterate `twittsIfollow` as a `List` of `Map`s

then you can use

```
@if(twittsIfollow != null) {
  @for(twitts <- twittsIfollow) {
   the value is:  @twitts.get("key")
  } 
}
```

Comment: yeah sorry, my focus was some other thing at that time, now i see. thanks.. but it says.. 
``value get is not a member of (java.lang.String, java.lang.String)``